# Can't connect to ssh with correct password

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a AWS EC2 instance I am trying to connect to. AWS uses Private key pairs for connection but for auto deploy reasons I want to connect via ssh with username and password.

Unfortunately even if the password is correct I get a Permission denied.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to log in with my private key and modify the ssh config file setting

- `UseLogin` to yes
- `PermitRootLogin` to yes
- `PasswordAuthentication` to yes

Then restarting the ssh service but it didn't work.

Here is the full debug of `ssh -v`:

```
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [3.10.215.57] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:QUcwAdw2W0FORZSFgIR0Y9e7fU74cs7qmdF/h0ii7x0
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 3.10.215.57
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ec2-3-10-215-57.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
```

Here as you can see it asks me the password a second time because it denied my access.

Comment: I'm not sure Amazon EC2 instances allow access without keys. For auto deployment, I would have thought you want keys anyway and not interactive logons?

Comment: [How to Enable Password Authentication in AWS ec2 Instances | by Rakesh Samal | Medium](https://medium.com/@rakeshwrites/how-to-enable-password-authentication-in-aws-ec2-instances-26fbdddd74b0) suggests that you would need to restart `sshd`. A reboot would probably have the same affect.

Comment: have you setup a **ubuntu** user's password after login in to the instance using the private key?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.